# conversion for unix timestamp to moment js not working properly in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, momentjs, unix-timestamp

This code:

```
let obj = moment.unix(1459382400).utc();
```

Works fine in Firefox 54, but not in Chrome 59.0.3071.109. In firefox it returns Date 2016-03-31T00:00:00.000Z which is the correct date, but in Chrome it returns Wed Mar 30 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (CDT) which is a day before the correct date.

I've been searching for a solution unsuccessfully. The 1459382400 unix timestamp has no time, but in chrome it does.

What am I missing.

Comment: the moment was not incorrect, moment represents a point of time, and both 2016-03-31T00:00:00.000Z and Wed Mar 30 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (CDT) represents the same moment in the time. I had to work with this, because I was unable to find a solution neither the official moment documentation neither accross the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function setTimezone(moment, timezone) {

var a = moment.toArray(); // year,month,date,hours,minutes,seconds as an array

moment = moment.tz(timezone);

moment.year(a[0])
    .month(a[1])
    .date(a[2])
    .hours(a[3])
    .minutes(a[4])
    .seconds(a[5])
    .milliseconds(a[6]);

return moment; // for chaining
};

var m = setTimezone(moment('2014-03-10T10:00'), "America/New_York");
console.log(m.format())
```

Use this function

Before using, consider updating moment. latest version has this issue fixed

Comment: I appreciate your response... I have the latest version of moment... today's version. I don't need to use timezone... just date.

Comment: date is wrong because timezone is wrong. See chrome is showing gmt -4 and i actually 4 hours behind the utc time. adding 4 hours will convert it to next date. Modify this function as you want to get date only

Comment: thats precisely what I want, to remove the timezone from the equation

Comment: @assembler remove timezone from equation means ?

Comment: Mr. @Shubham Singla it means take off the timezone from the moment object while it is been created.

Comment: @assembler take off time zone means new time in utc or local time?

Comment: it means new time in utc, I thank you for your interest, I have a solution already.